# iOS app update and crash on first view

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, app-store

I've an iOS app on the store and I need to make an update.
But I encountered a crash when running the new app (from xcode) when the app from the store is installed.

```
Unknown class XXXViewController in Interface Builder file.
```

I think this is because I changed the Custom Class of the first view in the storyboard, from `XXXViewController` to `YYYViewController`.
Why the package is only partially updated?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of investigation, and a TSI, it seems that it's a bug from XCode.

This issue does not occur when testing update with Apple Technical Note TN2285 as described here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2285/_index.html

As it happens, Xcode has some issues with properly removing old resources when doing a development build. This is because Xcode tries to only push changed files os that it can build faster. This is generally good during development, but has it’s downsides.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why its partially updated. I can suggest that you get on with it. Sort out the crash, get rid of the unknown class name in your interface builder and then writing the appropriate class name so that you can push an update that will work. The longer you wait the more users that have to suffer from this crash.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your YYYViewController.m is included in YourTarget -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources

Comment: Yes it is included. I don't have this issue when desinstalling the app first, then launch the new version from xCode...